# Apache Sqoop : scoop-import giving Undefined error.

Tags: mysql, hdfs, hadoop2, sqoop

I am working with Apache Hadoop and Apache Sqoop. And I'm trying to import the mysql tables into the hdfs.

Here is the command which i am executing:

```
sqoop-import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/billing_engine -username root -password root > --table cpDetail;
```

I have setup the Sqoop home environment variable as follows:

```
export SQOOP_HOME=/Users/bng/Documents/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha
export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin
```

But executing the above command, gives me the following error:

```
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
usage: dirname path
/Users/bng/Documents/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/bin/sqoop-import: line 26: /Users/bng/sqoop: Undefined error: 0
```

Here is the screenshot showing my name node:
[image]

Please suggest, where am i wrong?

Comment: why that redirection `>` after password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right command which i needed to use:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/billing_engine?useSSL=false --username bil --password bil --table cpdetail -m 1 --target-dir /sqoopFromMysql
```

The details of the command is as follows;

1. Sqoop import :  the command telling to use sqoop's import command
2. --connect :  indicating the connection to be used
3. jdbc:mysql://localhost/billing_engine?useSSL=false : connecting to mysql using the jdbc. The host for db is localhost and database name is billing_engine. useSSL=false specifies that we are not connecting over SSL layer.
4. --username bil --password bil : specifies the username and password for the database.
5. --table cpdetail : specifies the particular table
6. -m 1 : specifies the maps to be used
7. --target-dir /sqoopFromMysql : specifies the target directory in HDFS, where the data will be imported.